# What is the Best HW / OS Combination for Oracle 11g?

Tags: hardware, oracle, dell, oracle-11g, sun

My company is in the midst of upgrading our database hardware / software to support Oracle 11g.  We're considering the following hardware / OS combinations for the database server:

- Sun v890 (current hardware) / Solaris 10
- Sun T5120 / Solaris 10
- Sun T5120 / Linux
- Dell 810 / Solaris x86
- Dell 810 / Linux

As far as performance goes, do any of the above combinations have a discernable edge?  Are there any published trade studies or whitepapers that help make a case for a particular combo?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but I have set up Oracle 11g on a Dell 710 before with Red Hat Linux and it as worked well. I would recommend that if you do use Linux you go with Red Hat or you might have issues getting it to work and with support.  You can get CentOS to work with some fudging of a few text files.

Comment: Does Oracle recommend "Oracle Linux" now?  I can't remember if they stopped supporting RHEL directly but it's a fork from RHEL.

Comment: Does the fact that Oracle bought Sun give any sort of advantage to Solaris or Sun hardware?

Comment: From my personal experiences that fact that Oracle bought Sun is flat out disadvantage in any aspect.

Comment: IMHO Oracle had always optimized most on Sun most before its more recent love affair with Linux (RedHat before the JBoss purchase, then their own).

Answer (score 1):

An advantage to Solaris, if you're interested in partitioning / virtual hosts, is that Oracle permits licensing for fewer than the number of CPUs if using Solaris Containters, but not for Linux solutions like Xen or VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

We moved almost all of our Solaris boxes over to either Solaris x86 (64-bit) on HP blades or over to Oracle Linux (a rebadged RHEL) on HP blades. We had great success throughout, the migration went smoothly, we saw enormous performance benefits and they've proven to be stable and cost effective. This was against a large range of application with around 40% of them being Oracle DB boxes.

If I had to choose one platform I'd go with the Dell and Linux combo.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Linux...specifically the gains in performance through the new [Oracle Unbreakable Linux Kernel distribution](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/linux/ubreakable-enterprise-kernel-linux-173350.html). The kernel is compatible on Oracle or RedHat distributions, but brings forward a lot of enhancements from the newer Linux kernel (2.6.32) AND Non-uniform Memory Access while not waiting for RedHat EL 6 to come out. It is available on a public yum server for those that do not use Oracle Linux. I like CentOS of course for the free nature and the updates come out often times within hours of the upstream (RedHat) publish.

Answer (score 0):

It's been my experience that Oracle performs better on Solaris than Linux.  That might be a little outdated now though as it's been a few years.

For example I haven't tried Oracle with with the latest Linux kernels and filesystems.

If you have a copy of Oracle you might want to do some rudimentary testing on the different platforms.

Support for Oracle might be best under Solaris though and I suspect Oracle is tuned for Solaris somewhat.